# Search TextField for JSON Image not repeatable with using Marvel API

Tags: json, swift, textfield

My program is simple and my skills are very novice at this point. I've come to a standstill in my app and have searched for an answer if anyone could help I'd be so appreciative.

The app has a search textfield where I can search for a Marvel character and decode the image from the JSON. If I search for a character let's say "Deadpool" I get his image immediately like below:

[image]

However if I were to search again for another character from textfield the Image does not update and I still see Deadpool. Also if I misspell a name the program errors out with " Fatal error: Index out of range"

I see that when I type a character's name again the correct URL is being captured and passed to my URL String converter but does not go into my URL Session it just stops.
[image]

This is my code for my Json parser

```
func parseJSON(_ marvelData: Data) -> ResultsModel? {
  let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
  do {
    let decodedData = try decoder.decode(APIResults.self, from: marvelData)
            
            
    let path = decodedData.data.results[0].thumbnail.path
    let `extension` = decodedData.data.results[0].thumbnail.extension
            
    let imagePath = ResultsModel(pathString: path, xtensionString: `extension`)
            
    return imagePath
  } catch {
    delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error)
    return nil
  }
}
```

This is my URL manager function

```
func performRequest(with urlString: String) {
  if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
      if error != nil {
        // delegate goes here
        return
      }
                
      if let safeData = data {
        if let image = self.parseJSON(safeData) {
          delegate?.updateImage(self, results: image)
        }
      }
    }
    task.resume()
  }
}
```

Comment: Regarding the program error, it looks like if you misspell the character then `decodedData.data.results` is empty so trying yo access `[0]` will lead to the crash. Simply add a check before doing this, `if decodedData.data.results.isEmpty { return nil }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of the:

> Fatal error: Index out of range

error, that can be explained by this line in your JSON parser function:

`let path = decodedData.data.results[0].thumbnail.path`

Here you are assuming that there is *always at least one element* in the results array.

But as you say so yourself "if I misspell a name"...well in that case maybe there are no results to return, and if that is the case, asking for the character at location 0 in an empty array will give you the "Fatal error: Index out of range" error.

As you can see in [the documentation](https://developer.marvel.com/docs#!/public/getCreatorCollection_get_0) for the Marvel API call for characters, the `results` array is *optional* so you can't be sure it is always present.

### Suggestion

You need to ensure that there are actually content in the array before you start asking for it. Since you are always just interested in the first character you could do something like:

```
let decodedData = try decoder.decode(APIResults.self, from: marvelData)

guard let character = decodedData.data.results.first else { 
    // no character found so bail out
    return nil 
}         
let path = character.thumbnail.path
let `extension` = character.thumbnail.extension
            
let imagePath = ResultsModel(pathString: path, xtensionString: `extension`)
            
return imagePath
```

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you so much this what I was looking for! Still trying to wrap my head around JSON parsing :)

Comment: @Mark you're welcome, glad it worked :) On to the next frustrating problem eh :)